# Getting Fiscal year using Case statement in MDX Query gives Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, mdx, ssas-2012

I am using MDX query in Excel to get the data from the cube. And every July the Fiscal year gets changed and we have to change manually. Is there any way I can implement this case statement in following query?

```
SELECT 
  ( { [Dim ID].[ID Key].&[7]} ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT 
  ( { [Billing].[FY].&***[2015]*** } ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Billing DW])
) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Instead of year [2015] I want to write this case statement.

```
CASE 
  WHEN MONTH(getdate()) > 7 THEN YEAR(getdate()) + 1 
  ELSE YEAR(getdate()) 
END ;
```

Comment: if it important then you should implement a fiscal year hierarchy in your cube. Microsoft illustrate an implementation of this in their AdvWrks cube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some string manipulation and VB code to achieve this since MDX doesn't have a `getdate()` function.  As whytheq mentioned though, you will save yourself a lot of headache in the future to just include Fiscal Year on the dimension itself.

```
 SELECT ( { [Billing].[FY].&[2015] } )
```

would become

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN FORMAT(now(), "MM") > "07"
    THEN StrToMember("[Billing].[FY].&["+Format(now(), "yyyy")+"]").lead(1)
    ELSE
    StrToMember("[Billing].[FY].&["+Format(now(), "yyyy")+"]") END
```

Comment: Thanks you !! Really appreciate it !!

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create a member that represents the billing year you require, using IIF to do the selection based on the current month. Then use `strtomember()` to pick out the right member in the query.

Your original query would become something like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Current Month] AS MONTH(NOW())
     MEMBER [Current Year] AS YEAR(NOW())
     MEMBER [Billing Year] AS IIF([Current Month] > 7, [Current Year] + 1, [Current Year])
SELECT [Dim ID].[ID Key].&[7] ON COLUMNS,
       strtomember('[Billing].[FY].&[' + cstr([Billing Year].Value) + ']') ON ROWS
FROM [Billing DW]
```